# Electron-phonon coupling plotted as function of phonon bands

Tags: vasp, quantum-espresso, band-structure, phonon-dispersion, superconductivity

I'm looking to superimpose electron phonon coupling (EPC) constants per phonon band per k-point as is done in Figures 6c and 6d in this paper, essentially a "fat band" plot where the diameter of the circles on the phonon bands represents EPC magnitude https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1704505114#sec-3

I think this k-point dependent format is extremely helpful in showing how phonons couple to the electronic bands of the solid when in/out of phase between unit cells (ie at different k-points of high symmetry in the 1st Brilluoin zone), but every software I've seen will only compute DOS-like spectral functions or other k-point independent plots of EPC. I've examined EPC documentation for Quantum Espresso (which this paper lists as used in their methods) as well as other widely used softwares like EPW and Phonopy. The electronic bands I've plotted for my system are generated from DFT in VASP and the phonon bands (without EPC) are done with Vasp DFPT post-processed in Phonopy, but I'm open to using any software to get this sort of plot.

Can anyone tell me how I can go about making a phonon band diagram like this with EPC magnitude superimposed?

[image: Figures 6c and 6d from the linked paper]